# Using cefSharp how do I get the URL of the iframe in the LoadingStateChanged event?

Tags: .net, cefsharp

When I load a page into an iFrame my event handler is called

```
void webBrowser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
```

But when I look at e.Browser.FocusedFrame.Url the address is the address of the parent page. How do I access the URL for the iFrame?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the LoadingStateChanged use the FrameLoadEnd event instead. Then you can use the FrameLoadEndEventArgs.Frame.Url